# Fastest way to read and write data to file(s)?

Tags: vbscript, io

In a VBScript application, I need to log a few (50ish) parameters over time. Since using a database for this would be overkill, I'll do this with flat files.

There is one thread writing data into the files, each second.

The user can draw a plot of any variable.

I wonder what would be the most efficient way to do things:

- A single file:

  ```
  single.txt
  |Time|Param1|Param2|...|Param50|
  |1|0.5|1.8|...|0.24|
  ```
- One file per parameter:

  ```
  param1.txt
  |Time|Param|
  |1|0.5|

  param2.txt
  |Time|Param|
  |1|1.8|
  ```

For me, a single file would be easier to write, but more difficult to read and vice versa.

The file are meant to be no longer that 100k lines.

Is there a solution that is always better, 'theoretically', or is there a break-even point depending on the number of parameters?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Maxime

Comment: How long is "over time"? Is it a session of the application or it can expand to multiple sessions?

Comment: @Pankaj 1 to 20 hours, in a single session.
At the end of the session, the files would be deleted.

Comment: In that case, Arrays or Dictionary would be easier and faster.

Comment: I can't do it like this. It all runs within a business software, which limits my options, the write and the read need to be to a third party.

That aside, wouldn't a 50MB array be a bit big?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I didn't knew about 50MB. Now that you have clarified, reading and writing a 50MB file won't be fun. Arrays or Dictionaries would still be good idea as you can actually manipulate the size and there are number of inbuilt functions which will speed up retrieving data.

Comment: Write all values to one CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

@AnsgarWiechers answer was definitively the right one.
Writing to an .csv file, and querying it with ADO works perfectly.